# Capture picture using iPhone's volume-up button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application , how can I capture pictures using iPhone's **volume-up(+)** button while displaying on-screen actions/settings?

I want it to work in a similar way as it works in default camera application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the UIImagePickerController object, the volume button actions come built-in. So if you use this object in your app, you get very similar functionality to the built-in camera app, specifically -- if you press the volume up it will capture your image.

To use it, the rough process is as follows:

1. Create a UIImagePickerController object
2. Set its sourceType property to be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera and set its delegate
3. Implement your delegate methods to handle the picture you take and dismiss the camera
4. And then present the camera. The default is to show the camera controls on screen and you can either use those or use the volume button.

Answer (score 3):

Are you want to know a hardware volume buttons up-press, down-press notification?

Or,please explain more about when you press the volume buttons to take pictures?

If so, refer an [OpenSource](https://github.com/blladnar/RBVolumeButtons) example. **Looking at the code,  you can find a volume press-up/press-down event methods.**